# Named query method to order a Page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i'm new with JPA and i've spend days trying to figure out how to solve this. but simply i can't

i'm doing pagination on server side for my application using `PagingAndSortingRepository i can do it work fine, but when i try to add an order it breaks

Already i have this one working fine:

```
Page<Factura> findByEstadoNotAndFechaCreacionBetween(String estado, Date from, Date to, Pageable pageable);
```

but if i want to add at the end or middle `OrderByIdFacturaDesc` it stop of working also tried add `By` before the order and still isn't working

Also i've tried to do:

```
Page<Factura> findByEstadoNotOrderByIdFacturaDesc(String estado, Pageable pageable);
```

and works pretty fine, but i need filter on date.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to go for the @Query annotation to run this kind of query, it simplify the problem, and use LIMIT in that for pagination

Comment: Yeah you were right with use @Query, but i didn't need to use LIMIT, thanks for your guide :)